# Should tempdb be larger on a secondary replica?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, tempdb

I am working on SQL Server 2012 with Availability Groups.

On the secondary replica, the size of the tempdb datafile is roughly double that of the primary.  I am struggling to find information on whether this is normal or not?

The secondary replica is set up as a read-only replica.  All the server agent jobs check if they are executing on the primary node when they run, apart from backup jobs which only run on the secondary.  As far as I am aware we don't have any client applications that access the secondary replica directly.

Size examples (from `sp_helpfile`):

- Primary replica - tempdev: 12259456 KB
- Secondary replica - tempdev: 24828992 KB

Comment: In general, since Availability Groups work at the database level only, instance-level things (like TempDB) may and can behave differently.

Comment: After you next reboot collect the size a few times a day and then put the data in a pivot chart to see the trend. That will give you the baseline where you should keep your tempdb size. If you need the code to collect that information let me know.

Answer (score 3):

On secondary node, when used for read-only query, SQL enable ReadCommited Snapshot behind the scene.
If you have long running transaction that does read, that could explain why you used a lot more tempdb on that secondary node.

Answer (score 1):

**Should tempDB be larger on a secondary replica?**

It will depend on your workload.

I suggest you collect and save your tempdb file sizes at frequent intervals. Once you collect it for a while that represents your full workload cycle, you chart it and find your baseline. That is how I would decide the size of my tempdb database in all nodes.  Here is a code fragment you can use. Please test first. It will also take care of databases in `Always On Availability Group' and if your databases that are secondary.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @DBname varchar(MAX);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DBs') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #DBs;
END
CREATE TABLE #DBs (dbname sysname);


CREATE TABLE #DB_SizeData(
    [Servername] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [nvarchar](260) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](100) not null,
    [Type_Description] [nvarchar] (50),
    [CurrentFileSizeGB] [decimal](18, 1) NULL,
    [FileUsedSpaceGB] [decimal](18, 1) NULL,
    [FileFreeSpaceGB] [decimal](18, 1) NULL,
    [FilePercentFree] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [RecCreateDt] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO #DBs
--only choose online databases
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
--looking for online only 
WHERE [STATE] = 0
--excluding single_user and restricted user
AND   [user_access]=0
AND   [is_read_only]=0
--uncomment below line if you want to exclude system databases
AND   [NAME] NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') ; 

--get secondary replica db list
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AGdatabases') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #AGdatabases;
END

CREATE TABLE #AGdatabases
(dbname SYSNAME);

IF EXISTS (SELECT
AG.name AS [Name],
ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [PrimaryReplicaServerName],
ISNULL(arstates.role, 3) AS [LocalReplicaRole]
FROM master.sys.availability_groups AS AG
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as agstates
    ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas AS AR
    ON AG.group_id = AR.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS arstates
    ON AR.replica_id = arstates.replica_id AND arstates.is_local = 1
)

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #AGdatabases
SELECT DISTINCT
dbcs.database_name AS [DatabaseName]
FROM master.sys.availability_groups AS AG
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as agstates
   ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas AS AR
   ON AG.group_id = AR.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS arstates
   ON AR.replica_id = arstates.replica_id AND arstates.is_local = 1
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states AS dbcs
   ON arstates.replica_id = dbcs.replica_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS dbrs
   ON dbcs.replica_id = dbrs.replica_id AND dbcs.group_database_id = dbrs.group_database_id
WHERE ISNULL(arstates.role, 3) = 2 AND ISNULL(dbcs.is_database_joined, 0) = 1
ORDER BY  dbcs.database_name;
END
--exclude secondary replica databases
DELETE FROM #DBs WHERE dbname in
(SELECT dbname FROM #AGdatabases);

WHILE exists (SELECT * FROM #DBs)
BEGIN

SELECT TOP 1 @DBname = dbname
FROM #DBs

SELECT @SQL = '
USE '  +  QUOTENAME(@DBname) +' --to account for space or special characters in a datbase name
SELECT @@Servername,
DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
name AS FileName, 
type_desc AS Type_Description,
size/128.0/1024 AS CurrentSizeGB, 
CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0/1024 AS UsedSpaceGB ,
size/128.0/1024 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0/1024 AS FreeSpaceGB ,
((size/128.0/1024 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0/1024)/(size/128.0/1024))*100 as LogFilePercentFree
,getdate()
from [' + @DBname+ '].sys.database_files 
; 
'
INSERT INTO  #DB_SizeData
EXEC (@SQL)

DELETE FROM  #DBs
WHERE @DBname = dbname
END  

SELECT * FROM #DB_SizeData
DROP TABLE #DB_SizeData
DROP TABLE #DBs
```